# Отправка данных из формы

Tags: python, django

код страницы авторизации:

```
<!-- $(if chap-id) -->
    <form name="sendin" action="{{ link_login_only }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" />
        <input type="hidden" name="password" />
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="{{ link_orig }}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
    </form>

{% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/md5.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function doLogin() {
        document.sendin.username.value = document.login.username.value;
        document.sendin.password.value = hexMD5({{ chap_id }} + document.login.password.value + {{ chap_challenge }});
        document.sendin.submit();
        return false;
        }
    //-->
    </script>
<!-- $(endif) -->

<!-- removed $(if chap-id) $(endif)  around OnSubmit -->
        <form name="login" action="{{ link_login_only }}" method="post" onSubmit="return doLogin()" >
            <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="{{ link_orig }}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />

            <table width="100" style="background-color: #ffffff">
                <tr><td align="right">login</td>
                <td><input style="width: 80px" name="username" type="text" value="{{ username }}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td align="right">password</td>
                <td><input style="width: 80px" name="password" type="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td> </td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="OK" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  document.login.username.focus();
//-->
</script>
```

link_login_only это http://10.0.10.1/login
данные с сервера 10.0.10.2 шлются на микротик с адресом 10.0.10.1, по всем правилам они должны улетать но не тут то было, post запрос в пакетах вообще не видно, только как md5.js статика запрашивается и все. Django в режиме разработчика на порту 8000, есть мысль что стоит наверно его на nginx поставить и там все будет - но не факт. По идее могла быть и кривая настройка hotspot на микротике но при нажатии отправить post запрос не летит, а должен, так что дело скорее всего дело не в настройках микротика. (в walled garden адреса добавлены)

На радиус сервере запроса тоже не видно, везде тишина...

[image: пакеты]

Comment: Вся простыня, что вы выложили абсолютно ни к чему - оставьте только код, ответственный за отправку и обработку запросов.

Comment: Подправил, убрал все лишнее. Не ясна роль md5.js в отправке формы, подскажите что там javascript делает?

Comment: md5.js - уходит превращает введенный пароль пользователя в хеш md5 перед отправкой post данных. Но когда он срабатывает я не вижу. action="{{ link_login_only }}"   - куда ведет?

Comment: link_login_only это http://10.0.10.1/login микротик ос

Comment: form name="login" отправляет данные, но функция doLogin() перехватывает данные и заполняет форму form name="sendin" , которую дальше отправляет. Возможно убрать промежуточную форму, но кодировать пароль придется через js.

Comment: И как можно обойтись без промежуточной формы?

Comment: Добавил в ответ, за js точно не скажу, но должно так работать, при отладке лучше все поля отобразить.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант убрать ajax оставив только саму форму которая будет отправлена.

```html
 <form name="sendin" action="{{ link_login_only }}" method="post">
        <input type="input" name="username" />
        <input type="hiden" name="password" />
        <input type="input" name="pass" onchange="document.sendin.password.value = hexMD5({{ chap_id }} + document.sendin.pass.value + {{ chap_challenge }})"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="{{ link_orig }}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </form>
```

Поле пароля скрыто, вместо него псевдо поле из которого берется значение, обрабатывается скриптом и подставляется